# The document has moved Calling a Rest API method

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, curl, restful-architecture

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.
I've defined this Rest method to update a User

```
@PutMapping(path = "/api/users/{id}", 
                        consumes = "application/json", 
                        produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser
                                    (HttpServletRequest request, 
                                    @PathVariable long id,
                                    User user) {

        System.out.println(user);
        saveUser (user)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);

    }
```

I call this method from the console, using

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIazUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyaWNhcmQub2xsZUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1MjgxMTM3NTIsImlhdCI6MTUyNzUwODk1Mn0.QdxabtU1U87pYvyTstT1EG3E6uVpLo2mXCF0FF8iD6acKoAXKl_A0-eV_GrpOFg5FF1qR6B7llI5_USJL85YTQ" -d {"id":1,"username":"pere.peris@gmail.com","email":"pere.peris@gmail.com","firstName”:”Pere”,”lastName”:”PERIS”,”country”:”CAT”,”enabled":true} "http://127.0.0.1:2233/elcor/api/users/1"
```

but what I see in the console is really strange

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/gmail/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/gmail/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'R'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'P'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'E'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'i'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'a'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'm'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'm'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'c'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 't'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 't'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 't'
curl: (3) Port number ended with 't'
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 14
curl: (3) Port number ended with 't'
{"id":1,...."enabled":false}
```

Comment: You have to escape the content which you want to send as body (i.e. everything after -d within the {} ). At the moment, the console interprets the {} as commands, not as a string which you want as an input for curl.

Comment: @dunni, please convert to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the body content that you provided to the -d argument and surround it in quotes like this:

```
-d "{\"id\":1,\"username\":\"pere.peris@gmail.com\",\"email\":\"pere.peris@gmail.com\",\"firstName\":\"Pere\",\"lastName\":\"PERIS\",\"country\":\"CAT\",\"enabled\":true}"
```

Otherwise everything outside of quotes will be treated as a command by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be an issue with the URL. Try printing the request URL in your logger or to the console from your code. Im sure it wont match your curl request.

Comment: I guess it match because in the Eclipse console I see  the System.out.println(user);